# Target nth of type inside bootstrap columns

Tags: css

With WordPress attributes you can't have the same selector so I need to use something like nth of type but it isn't working so I obviously don't have the correct selectors. Here is the html

```
<div class="wp-block-blocks">
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5 class="display-5">55K</h5>
                    <p>asfasf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5 class="display-5">55K</h5>
                    <p>afsasf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5 class="display-5">55K</h5>
                    <p>safasffas</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

The selectors I am trying to set are for each h5 and p tag

For the h5 I have tried this but no joy

```
.col-md-4 h5:nth-of-type(1)
.col-md-4 h5:nth-of-type(2)
.col-md-4 h5:nth-of-type(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
.col-md-4:nth-child(1) h5
```

Comment: This is working, thanks! I just can't accept the answer yet

Comment: you can accept it in a while, thanks